# Construction of homogeneous Siegel domain from j-algebra

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am reading bounded homogeneous domain from Piatetski-Shapiro's
book ``Automorphic functions and the geometry of classical domains''
and have questions on how to construct homogeneous Siegel domain
from a normal $j$-algebra.

Recall Siegel domains of genus $2$ are $S=\{ (z,u) \in
\mathbb{C}^{n+m}  | \operatorname{Im} z-F(u,u) \in V\}$, where
$F(u,v)$ is a Hermitian form defined on $\mathbb{C}^m$ and takes
values in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Moreover, $F(u,u) \in \overline{V}$ and
$F(u,u)=0$ iff $u=0$. Here $V$ an open convex cone contained in
$\{y_i>0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\overline{V}$ its closure
under the Euclidean topology.

Let $D$ be a homogeneous Siegel domain of genus $2$ and $Auto(D)$
its full group of holomorphic automorphism,
Gindikin-Piatetski-Shapiro-Vinberg proved that there exists a
maximal (simply-) transitive subgroup $S$ of $Auto(D)$ that is
solvable and split over $\mathbb{R}$. Such a group acts on $D$ by
affine transformations on $\mathbb{C}^{n+m}$. The Lie algebra of $S$
is a normal $j$-algebra (defined on P51 of Shapiro).

Shapiro's book P26 gave an example of bounded homogeneous
unsymmetric in $\mathbb{C}^4$ in the form of Siegel domain. Let
$
V=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^3 |\, y_1y_2-y_3^2>0, y_1>0 \}
$ the cone in $R^{3}$
and $F(u,v)=(u\bar{v}, 0, 0)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^1$ and takes
value in $\mathbb{C}^3$, the corresponding Sigel domain is
$
D=\{ (z=x+\sqrt{-1}y, u) \in \mathbb{C}^3 \, | \,\, y_1-|u|^2>0,
(y_1-|u|^2)y_2-y_3^2>0 \}
$

On P64 of Shapiro's book he sketched a real $8$-dim normal
$j-$algebra and mentioned it corresponds to a nonsymmetric domain in
$\mathbb{C}^4$. A detailed construction of this $j$-algebra was
carried out by p69 of D'Atri's 1980 paper ``The curvature of
homogeneous Siegel domains'' (J. Differential Geom. 15 (1980), no.
1, 61-70.)

Shapiro's book P66-73 explains how to construct Siegel domain
from normal $j$-algebra. My question is how to make it work for this
specific example in $\mathbb{C}^4$.

For the convenience, I am copying down D'Atri's construction (p69 of
D'Atri's 1980 paper): Take $\mathfrak{s}=\operatorname{Span} \{jr_1,
j r_2, r_1, r_2, x, jx\} + Z$ where $Z$ is a real $2$-dim space and
$j^{2}=-1$, then define all nonzero Lie brackets by:

\begin{align*}
[jr_, r_1]=r_1, [jr_1, x]=\frac{1}{2}x, [jr_1, jx]=\frac{1}{2}jx,
[jr_1, z]=\frac{1}{2}z, \,\,\, z\in Z; \\
[jr_2, r_2]=r_2, [jr_2, x]=-\frac{1}{2}x, [jr_1, jx]=\frac{1}{2}jx,
[r_2, x]=jx,\\
[x,jx]=-r_1, [z,z'] \in \mathbb{R} \, r_1,  \text{for any} \, z, z' \in Z.
\end{align*}
Then define the $1$-form $\omega$ by $\omega(r_1)=1$ and $\omega
(r_2)=t$ and $\omega$ vanishes on $Z+\operatorname{span}\{j r_1, j
r_2, x, jx\}$, then $\mathfrak{s}$ is a normal $j$-algebra.

Define $\mathfrak{s}_{-1}=\operatorname{span}\{jx, r_1, r_2\}$,
$\mathfrak{s}_{-\frac{1}{2}}=Z$, and
$\mathfrak{s}_{-}=\operatorname{span}\{x, jr_1, jr_2\}$. The cruical
step to recover the Siegel domain is to solve the adjoint orbit of
$r=r_1+r_2$ by the action of $\exp_{\mathfrak{s_0}}$ on
$\mathfrak{s}_{-1}=\mathbb{R}^{3}$. It is exactly the cone $V$ in
the construction Siegel domain. Recall that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(s_0))(r)=r+\operatorname{ad}(s_0)(r)
+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{ad}^2(s_0)(r)+\cdots+. \,\,\, s_0 \in
\mathfrak{s}_0
\end{equation}

Since we have all Lie brackets in $\mathfrak{s}$, so the adjoint
orbit can be computed, For example since $[jr, v]=v$ for any $v \in
\mathfrak{s}_{-1}$, we have $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(c \,
jr))(v)=e^{c} v$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$. So we know $V$ is a
cone in $\mathfrak{s}_{-1}$ in the sense that if $v \in V$ then
$\lambda v \in V$ for any $\lambda>0$.

Question 1: However, to determine $V$ explicitly seems very tedious,
can anyone suggest a more doable approach? Eventually it should be proved that the normal $j$-algebra in the above corresponds to the above domain in $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Question 2: If we realize this Siegel domain as a bounded domain in
$\mathbb{C}^4$, how much can we say about its boundary, except
knowing it is pseudoconvex? I would like to know the regularity of its boundary.